# Express is applying HTML entities to JSON bodies

Tags: node.js, json, express

We have a NodeJS based application using express and body-parser. The server is listening for REST requests, in JSON format. We are running into an issue whereby certain characters in the request are being HTML/XML escaped, and we strongly suspect something on the express or body-parse side is doing this, but we can't work out what is doing this.

In our test scenario we make a request with curl:

```
curl 'http://localhost:6009/stores/1561289s12' \                                                           ajmas@ghostwalker-echo
  -X 'PUT' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' \
  --data-raw $'{"name":"O\'Neil"}' \
  --compressed
```

On the server when we look at the `name` value in `req.body`, it comes out as:

```
O&#x27;Neil
```

What leads us to point the finger at express or body-parser is when we check with Wireshark we see the body as we sent it.

We initialised JSON parsing as follows:

```
  app.use(express.json({}));
```

- Express version is 4.17.1
- Node JS version: 14.15.1

This project also make use of express-validator.

Can anyone suggest anything that could cause this issue?

Comment: tested with this code, works fine: https://pastebin.com/yHWbMVy8

Comment: Are you sure there's not something between express and your front-end? apache/nginx? iis?

Comment: Testing on localhost, curl straight to nodejs server on localhost. Will check if there is some middleware causing issues, since Roland's test was fine.

Comment: I appreciate this is not necessarily the best presented question, but I won't delete it, since this is the sort of question I am sure will be part of a search at some point, based on previous experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to pay attention to, is that [express-validator](https://express-validator.github.io/) does more than validation and can modify or '[sanitise](https://medium.com/dataseries/introduction-to-request-body-validation-in-express-apps-with-express-validator-7b9725ca780d)' data. For this reason if anything is being modified between reception and viewing the value in `req.body`, then checking the settings of the validators is a good place to start.

In this case the behaviour can be attributed to `escape: true` or `escape()`, which applies the HTML style entities to the values.

Example of sanitisation, in express validators:

```
export default [
  body('name').trim().escape()
]
```

```
export default {
    name: {
        in: ['body'],
        trim: true,
        escape: true
}
```

Removing the 'escape' option or function call would resolve this.